# store objects in database

Tags: database

I have lot of objects, each can have many different kind of attributes. a lot of the attributes overlap, for example, many objects have the attribute "name".
Since there are many type of objects, if there is a table constructed for each set of objects with same set of attributes, it will take lot of tables.

Currently I'm using a mysql, and it is stored this way.

```
object_id|attribute_id|data
```

There are a few tables like this, different table have different type of data.
For example, in a Integer table, it only store integers

So I can store all kind of object in the system and it is still possible to do filtering and sorting according to the data of the attributes. It make queries a bit more complex and I don't think it is efficient.

Is this is only way to do it in mysql or other relational databases?
Should I try to find other database models for this problem?

**EDIT**
I did some research, it seems what I need is a Document-oriented database with the power of SQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to go with a [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system)-like document-oriented database, I think you should look into [**mongoDB**](http://www.mongodb.org/):

> A key goal of MongoDB is to bridge the
>   gap between key/value stores (which
>   are fast and highly scalable) and
>   traditional RDBMS systems (which are
>   deep in functionality).

Comment: Another benefit of MongoDB that sounds like it is directly applicable to your situation is that you can have all your different types of objects that are similar but not identical in one collection (analogous to a table in MySQL). If you use a good ORM like Doctrine, it can even automatically differentiate between the types of objects and translate them into the correct object in PHP when it loads them from the database. Not sure what language you're using, but I bet there's something similar if it's not PHP.

Answer (score 5):

I think what you want to do is research the area called "object relational mapping". It is a big area with many solutions. Some are used in frameworks, such as ""ActiveRecord used in Rails.

Answer (score 4):

Your design is called Object-Attribute-Value (OAV).  It's one way to map objects to a relational database.  It's generally very slow, but very flexible.  If your class definitions change constantly (or change dynamically) this may be your only choice.

You can use Object-Relational-Mapping (ORM).  It's another way to make objects to a relational database.  It's much faster, and somewhat less flexible.  If your class definitions don't change very often (and don't change dynamically) this is a far, far better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Using one table is possible, and probably preferable.  Have a table column for each of attributes from all of the object types.  Then add one more column to indicate the 'object type'.  You can get all the objects of one type out of the table with a simple query for rows with a particular object type name.

Comment: that would work if space isn't a issue and there is only a few different attributes.
While space isn't a issue here, there are a lot of attributes(potentially hundreds of them). databases like mysql have a limit on how much a row can store, thus render it impossible.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using an ORM (which is a very good idea), is to instead use the language's in-built serialization functionality (if it has one, otherwise a library instead) to transform the object into a byte buffer, and store that in a database, with a suitable key to look it up.  This works pretty well with key-value databases such as memcached.

Comment: that is a good idea. but that remove the real benefit of a relational database. If there is no filtering and sorting required, clearly this would be the best practice.(in fact, a key/value database like Tokyo Cabinet is good enough). But I have needs like find all object with attribute x larger than 10. This design would require the system read all the object into the memory and filter such objects.